# What is the difference between a probability measure and a probability density function?

Tags: probability, density-function, measure-theory

During my research, I have repeatedly come across the terms *probability measure* and *probability density function* (pdf). I am familiar with the concept of a pdf, but I am not entirely sure how probability measures relate to pdfs, or where exactly the differences lie in theoretical terms. I have since combed StackExchange (such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1073744/distinguishing-probability-measure-function-and-distribution) and [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563949/difference-in-probability-measure-vs-probability-distribution) question), and visited the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) for probability measures, but I still cannot see the difference, so I imagine I must be missing a nuance.

Hence my question: Could you check my understanding, and - if necessary - correct it?

To provide an example for context, let us consider the continuous-valued example of *human body height*. Let us denote the height of a person in meters as a random variable $X$, which maps a person's physical height to a corresponding real value $x$. In that case:

- we could define a **probability density function** $p(x)$ over all theoretically possible heights $x$. The pdf must be non-negative for all $x$, i.e. $p(x)\geq0 \; \forall \; x$, and it must integrate to $1$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx=1$. We can integrate $p(x)$ over subintervals to learn the probability that a person's height is in this interval.
- the definition of a **probability measure** seems related. Let us denote the set of all possible body heights $x$ as $S_1$. Based on this set, we design another set $S_2$ which contains $S_1$ and all possible subsets of $S_1$. The probability measure then assigns values between $0$ and $1$ to each entry in $S_2$, with the condition that the entry $\{\text{all }S_1\}$ in $S_2$ is assigned $1$, $\{\}$ is assigned $0$, and certain additivity properties are met (see the image below, taken from Wikiedpa)
  [image]

**Concerning my understanding of the difference**: A pdf $p(x)$ can assign values $\geq1$ to $x$, as it describes a density and only requires that the integral over all $x$ be equal to $1$. The limitation of probability measures to values below $1$ would probably correspond to a role more similar to integrating (vanishingly small) sub-intervals of $p(x)$. Is this the distinction between pdfs and probability measures? Why is this distinction important? Am I missing or misunderstanding something?

Comment: PDFs, by definition, exist only for measures absolutely continuous with respect to a reference measure (usually Lebesgue).  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298293 is relevant.

Answer (score 4):

A probability density function induces a probability measure with Reimann-Stiljes integration, but the space of probability measures is bigger. Take, as an example, the [Cantor distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_distribution) which has no probability density function, but whose distribution function, the Cantor function, meets criteria of a probability measure, (i.e. it is [cadlag](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CadlagFunction.html#:%7E:text=A%20cadlag%20function%20is%20a,sometimes%20abbreviated%20%22RCLL%22), tends to 0 as $x \rightarrow -\infty$ and tends to 1 as $x \rightarrow \infty$). The Cantor function is an intuitive and elementary example in measure theory of a function that is continuous measurably everywhere, has derivative of 0 measurably everywhere, but is not constant.

[image]

Comment: Or just take the singular point mass at zero for the sure event.

Comment: (+1) he Cantor distribution has density uniformly equal to one wrt the Cantor measure!